# PHP - Concatenate / cascade multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I've realized I need to stop banging my head and ask for help...

I have the following array:

```
$permissionTypes = array(
        'system' => array(
            'view' => 'View system settings.',
            'manage' => 'Manage system settings.'
        ),
        'users' => array(
            'all' => array(
                'view' => 'View all users.',
                'manage' => 'Manage all users.'
            )
        ),
        'associations' => array(
            'generalInformation' => array(
                'all' => array(
                    'view' => 'View general information of all associations.',
                    'manage' => 'Manage general information of all associations.'
                ),
                'own' => array(
                    'view' => 'View general information of the association the user is a member of.',
                    'manage' => 'Manage general information of the association the user is a member of.'
                )
            )
    ));
```

I'm trying to collapse / cascade the keys into a one-dimension array like so:

```
array(
    'system_view',
    'system_manage',
    'users_all_view',
    'users_all_manage',
    'associations_generalInformation_all_view',
    'associations_generalInformation_all_manage',
    'associations_generalInformation_own_view',
    'associations_generalInformation_own_manage'
)
```

I could use nested loops, but the array will be an undefined number of dimensions.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
public function iterateKeys(array $array, $joiner, $prepend = NULL) {
    if (!isset($formattedArray)) { $formattedArray = array(); }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            array_push($formattedArray, $joiner . $this->iterateKeys($value, $joiner, $key));
        } else {
            $formattedArray = $prepend . $joiner . $key;
        }

    }
    return $formattedArray;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Use recursion to handle arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: @rpaskett: I'm not interested in simply flattening the array. I want to concatenate the sub-array keys onto the parent array keys. Please take a look at the example.

Comment: @Barmar: That is what I'm trying. I've added my sample code. Do you see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
public function iterateKeys(array $array, $joiner, $prepend = NULL) {
    if (!isset($formattedArray)) {
       $formattedArray = array(); 
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $formattedArray = array_merge($formattedArray, $this->iterateKeys($value, $joiner, $prepend . $joiner . $key));
        } else {
            $formattedArray[] = $prepend . $joiner . $key;
        }

    }
    return $formattedArray;
}
```

Since the recursive call returns an array, you need to use `array_merge` to combine it with what you currently have. And for the non-array case, you need to push the new string onto the array, not replace the array with a string.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with array_merge. Works perfect. (Typo FYI: $formatted_array should be $formattedArray.)

Comment: FYI, I added the following prior to the return to eliminate the prepend on the final array:
 if (is_null($prepend)) {
  foreach ($formattedArray as $key => $value) {
   if(!(strpos($value, $joiner) === false)) {
    $formattedArray[$key] = substr($value, 1);
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function flattern(&$inputArray, $tmp = null, $name = '')
{
    if ($tmp === null) {
        $tmp = $inputArray;
    }

    foreach($tmp as $index => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            flattern($inputArray, $value, $name.'_'.$index);

            if (isset($inputArray[$index])) {
                unset($inputArray[$index]);
            }
        } else {
            $inputArray[$name.'_'.$index] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $inputArray;
}

var_dump(flattern($permissionTypes));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function flattenWithKeys(array $array, array $path = []) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $currentPath = array_merge($path, [$key]);

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenWithKeys($value, $currentPath));
        } else {
            $result[join('_', $currentPath)] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$flattened = flattenWithKeys($permissionTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me.

```
function array_key_append($source_array, $return_array = array(), $last_key = '', $append_with = "#")
{
    if(is_array($source_array))
    {
        foreach($source_array as $k => $v)
        {
            $new_key = $k;
            if(!empty($last_key))
            {
                $new_key = $last_key . $append_with . $k;
            }
            if(is_array($v))
            {
                $return_array = array_key_append($v, $return_array, $new_key, $append_with);
            } else {
                $return_array[$new_key] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

$StandardContactRequestDataforALL = array_key_append($StandardContactRequestDataforALL, $return_array = array(), $last_key = '', $append_with = "#");