# List all paths of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

#### So I got this:

```
$tree = [
    array(
        'name' => 'One1',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'One2',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'One3',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'One4',
        'children' => [
            array(
                'name' => 'Two1',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Two2',
                'children' => [
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Three1',
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Two3',
            ),
        ]
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'One5',
    ),
];
```

#### And I'm looking for a way to have this output (recursively):

- One1
- One2
- One3
- One4 › Two1
- One4 › Two2 › Three1
- One4 › Two3
- One5

#### As far as I go I have this function

```
function getValuesPaths(array $tree, $glue = ' > ') {
    $branches = array();
    foreach ($tree as &$item) {
        $piece = $item['name'];
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            if (count($item['children'])>1) {
                $leafs = self::getValuesPaths($item['children']);
                foreach ($leafs as $item) {
                    $branches[] = $piece . $glue . $item;
                }
            }   
        } else {
            $branches[] = $piece;
        }
    }
    return $branches;
}
```

This output the following paths:

- One1
- One2
- One3
- One4 > Two1
- One4 > Two3
- One5

It wasn't supposed to find the `One4 > Two2 > Three1`?

Comment: What have you tried and where does it fail? This is not a 'write my code for me' website.

Comment: Gets you most of the way there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751362/php-concatenate-cascade-multidimensional-array-keys/

Comment: @JanDoggen sorry… I've tried some of the solutions here in _the Stack_ but many of them, like #deceze shown it's about creating the path of the keys not the values.

At the moment I've melted my brain far to long trying to solve it and asked for some help.

Answer (score 2):

May help you…

```
function getKeyPaths(array $tree, $glue = '.')
{
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            $results = getKeyPaths($mixed, $glue);
            foreach ($results as $k => &$v) {
                $paths[$key . $glue . $k] = $v;
            }
            unset($results);
        } else {
            $paths[$key] = $mixed;
        }
    }

    return $paths;
}
```

Comment: awesome solution!