# how to get all keys of this multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have similar problem, which is here: [solved Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234852/how-to-get-all-the-key-in-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

But I would like to get such an array in return as final result for this demo array in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234852/how-to-get-all-the-key-in-multi-dimensional-array-in-php).

thanks a lot!

return array I would like to get:

```
    [0] => "0.name "
    [1] => "0.id "
    [2] => "0.phone "
    [3] => "0.Base.city "
    [4] => "0.EBase.city "
    [5] => "0.Qty "
    [6] => "1.name "
    [7] => "1.id "
    [8] => "1.phone "
    [9] => "1.Base.city "
    [10]=> "1.EBase.city "
    [11]=> "1.Qty "
```

I have tried this: But does not work:

```
        function array_flat(array $myarr)            
        {            
            $myline = "";            
            foreach ($myarr as $key => $value)            
                {            
                if ( $myline == "" ){$myline=sprintf("%s",$myarr[$key]);}            
                else {$myline=sprintf("%s%s",$myline,$myarr[$key]);}            
                }            
            return array($myline);            
        }            

        function array_keys_multi(array $array)            
        {            
            $keys = array();            

            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {            
            $keys[] = $key;            

            if (is_array($value)) {            
                $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($value));            
            }            
                else {            
                    $keys = array_flat($keys);            
                }            

            }            

            return $keys;            
        }
```

Moreover I have found this:Maybe it could help to solve my request:
[get all path of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795571/list-all-paths-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: array_keys() ?http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Do you mean that you want all keys from the key 1 of your array?

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you want the recursive keys as a string? Do you want a new array containing all keys? If the latter, how do you want to represent recursively found keys? As a new recursive array or something like dot-separation (e.g. 0.EBase.city) ? 

Please update question with more info...

Comment: @Nukeface thanks for your help, please see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

Yes this link did what I wanted:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795571/list-all-paths-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

```
             function getKeyPaths(array $tree, $glue = '_')                    
             {                                                                 
                 $paths = array();                                             
                 foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {                          
                     if (is_array($mixed)) {                                   
                         $results = getKeyPaths($mixed, $glue);                
                         foreach ($results as $k => &$v) {                     
                             $paths[$key . $glue . $k] = $v;                   
                         }                                                     
                         unset($results);                                      
                     } else {                                                  
                         $paths[$key] = $mixed;                                
                     }                                                         
                 }                                                             

                 return $paths;                                                
             }
```

to call it by:

```
     print_r(getKeyPaths($jsonquotesum));
```

Comment: Hi @Walter, though the link may have helped you, posting the solution (the code) that made it work for you in here would help others in the future. Especially since the link contains multiple code blocks ;)

Comment: @Nukeface thanks for trying to help, but I was faster (in searching the web :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use array_key().
You will get all the keys.
doc here:

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php

Comment: no that is not correct, I think. It must be recursively through the whole tree. But the output should be like me request.